# The background of a paragraph element extends to fill a form

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a form with contains several input and textarea elements. I also have some paragraph text which I use as a submit button which can be seen in the code below.

**HTML:**

```
<form action="form.php">
    <input type="text">
    <textarea style="float: left;"></textarea>
    <textarea style="float: right;"></textarea>
    <p id="btn" onclick="document.forms[0].submit();">Submit</p>
</form>
```

And here is the styling that applies to this element:

**CSS:**

```
#btn {
width: 180px;
margin: 40px auto;
background-color: #CFD8DC;
}
```

It is positioned at the bottom of the form after all the other elements. For some reason which I cannot understand, the coloured background of the paragraph element extends to fill the height of the form. The width would also fill to extend the form, but a width has been specified.

This does not seem to happen anywhere but the between the form elements. I would also like to specify, I'm using the Foundation, though I don't think this affects this as I use the same styling somewhere else and this problem does not occur.

**The question:**

1. What causes this?
2. How can the background only be displayed behind the paragraph element inside the form?

Comment: Can you please add your whole form HTML, and the form related CSS? Likely the issue is somewhere in there. Possibly the background is set on the form or the form somewhere else, or your missing a closing tag somewhere.

Comment: Your css works fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/saumil_sss/z0xapmr8/ . Could you add the HTML

Comment: Even with your new HTML, it still works as expected in [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/z0xapmr8/1/). Also, what margins do you want for the paragraph? It uses the ones for `#btn`, not the one for `p`.

Comment: Just added the HTML for the form.

Comment: @PavSidhu I'm afraid you may have to add some more CSS too. You know what, just give a link to your site, it will be easier.

Comment: I used a paragraph as a button because I used the same styling and element as on another part of the website, though not for a form. I just took the styling from their and placed it in here.

Comment: @MrLister Here is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/7ypgue06/. Why doing this, I found when removing the floats from the textarea elements, the button's background did not extend to the top. So I found the problem but not the answer. (I will put the solution as an answer to this question after)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem to this question was that their were floated elements before the submit button which messed around with the positioning. By applying this to the paragraph submit button:

```
clear: both;
```

The background did not extend to fill the form.

Comment: Your problem is much more interesting now that I can actually see it.

Comment: @MrLister you don't happen to know the reason why the width and height of the elements below a floated element get messed up?

Comment: I'm not sure yet. The problem also goes away if you don't give the p any margins instead of removing the floats from the textareas. Of course then the p ends up in the wrong position... must do some more experimenting. Perhaps all you need is a `clear`; then you can leave the floats in place. [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/7ypgue06/2/)). I still am not sure why though.